# To retrieve access token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a MVC application to escalate work to other person inside my organization. I have added all the members in my organization to AAD,
and registered an application there, created app service and linked that app service to registered app with SSO enabled.

Now every time someone visits the app, they can login successfully using their respective credential.

What I want to do know is to retrieve all the members in my AAD and display them inside dropdown list so that anyone can escalate to others by just looking in the dropdown list.

I have tried with sample graph SDK to get the name of users in my organization
with this code

```
    private string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
    private string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
    private string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
    private string scopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphScopes"];

public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID, httpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
        //var cachedItems = tokenCache.ReadItems(appId); // see what's in the cache

        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            appId, 
            redirectUri,
            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
            userTokenCache,
            null);

        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' }), cca.Users.First());
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            throw new ServiceException(
                new Error
                {
                    Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                    Message = Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded,
                });
        }
    }
```

with some change in scope.

```
<add key="ida:AppId" value="xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx"/>
<add key="ida:AppSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:55065/"/>
<add key="ida:GraphScopes" value="User.ReadBasic.All User.Read Mail.Send Files.ReadWrite"/>
```

This enables me to get basic details of all user in my organization.
But how I can achieve this in my app where authentication related stuffs are done in azure only, and there is no code for authentication and authorization in entire solution.

Thanks

Subham, NATHCORP, INDIA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is overly broad and doesn't include a description of what you have tried and what errors/blockers you encountered.

Comment: I have edited my question with more description about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how I can achieve this in my app where authentication related stuffs are done in azure only, and there is no code for authentication and authorization in entire solution.

Based on my understanding, you are using the build-in feature [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). You could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) to configure your web app to use AAD login. And you need to configure the required permissions for your AD app as follows:

[image]

**Note:** For Azure AD graph, you need to set the relevant permissions for the **Windows Azure Active Directory** API. For Microsoft Graph, you need to configure the **Microsoft Graph** API.

Then, you need to configure additional settings for your web app. You could access https://resources.azure.com/, choose your web app and update App Service Auth Configuration as follows:

[image]

**Note:** For using Microsoft Graph API, you need to set the `resource` to `https://graph.microsoft.com`. Details, you could follow [here](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/).

For retrieving the access token in your application, you could get it from the request header `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN`. Details, you could follow [Working with user identities in your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#working-with-user-identities-in-your-application).

Moreover, you could use [Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) package for Microsoft Azure Active Directory Graph API, [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) package for Microsoft Graph API using the related access token.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for sharing your knowledge. It would really help me.

Comment: I have requested header X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN to get token and have retrieved it.
But when I am calling api to get my details,
   'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/'

It is showing error with message that "InvalidAuthenticationToken"

Comment: It seems that your jwt access_token is invalid. You could use https://jwt.io/ to decode your token and make sure the `aud` is `https://graph.microsoft.com` and the `exp` is valid. I assumed that you did not configure the `additionalLoginParams` via accessing https://resources.azure.com/.